# How to create Telerik grid in Windows Phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, telerik, rad-controls

I am new to develop windows phone application , i have a small Query that is Is it possible to show data in Grid format in windows phone7 application using Telerik Radcontrols.If it is possible please suggest me how it is doing or can you provide any link .

Please genius help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as Telerik Grid for Windows Phone 7. You either have to create your own custom control to achieve the grid like presentation in UI

Comment: You can see a full list of all of Telerik's WP controls at: http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls.aspx